# Module 'BrightcovePlayerSDK' not found after upgrading to 0.63

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I have just upgraded to React Native 0.63 and can no longer build my app due to the following error

`Module 'BrightcovePlayerSDK' not found`

I tried adding it as a custom pod in my podfile but this did not work. Instead i have followed the instructions here https://github.com/brightcove/brightcove-player-sdk-ios to install manually. This now gives me the error

`No visible @interface for 'BCOVOfflineVideoManager' declares the selector 'requestVideoDownload:parameters:completion:'`

I have checked the framework search path is correct but i'm not sure what this error means.

I have just upgraded to Xcode 12.5 and here is my podfile now:

````
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'ProjectcNameApp' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

  target 'ProjectcNameAppTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  # use_flipper!
  # post_install do |installer|
  #   flipper_post_install(installer)
  # end
end```
````

Comment: Have you solved this issue? Can you help me?

Comment: I also am seeing this issue - any post of solution would help!

Comment: I did find that there is a similar method on BCOVOfflineVideoManager that just needs mediaSelections as an input as well. This solved my build issue, but may need more than :nil input in order to actually function properly. Hope this helps others that might have this issue!